# Updating A boolean value in MS SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, boolean, bit

I am having a hard time with this one. I can't seem to identify what't wrong. It is not updating my data on vote stat but it updates the vote count..

```vb
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader

'  Try

Dim president As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PRESIDENT WHERE name=@name ", con) ' + ComboBox1.Text + "';", con)
president.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ComboBox1.Text)
myreader = president.ExecuteReader()

While myreader.Read()
    prevote = myreader.Item("VoteCount")
    prevote = prevote + 1
End While

myreader.Close()

president.CommandText = "Update President set [VoteCount]= " & prevote & " where [Name] ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
president.Connection = con
president.ExecuteNonQuery()
president.Dispose()

Dim LRN As Int64
LRN = TextBox3.Text

Using Stud_Vote_Stat As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE Voters SET [VoteStat] = 1  WHERE [VOTERSNAME] = @VOTERSNAME", con)
    Stud_Vote_Stat.Parameters.Add("@VOTERSNAME", SqlDbType.TEXT).Value = TextBox2.R
    Stud_Vote_Stat.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make to much sense. What do you try to do?

Comment: That code is replacing a good Parameterized SELECT query with a BAD concatenated UPDATE query.  `Dim rows = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows were updated.  You should also use `Add` rather than `AddWithValue`  And a `Using` block would remove the need to close and dispose things.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am trying to update the a column VoteStat (datatype is bit) to true so that, the student whose LRN (primary key) can no longer vote in the future because the student already voted. Default vaue is set to false.

Comment: @Plutonix  that code works well if I am updating a voteCount (adding 1 to its value), the datatype is number, but it doesn't seem to work with VoteStat where the data type is bit.

Comment: In my access database, it works well.

Comment: I also tried this code in management studion and works great.

update dbo.voters set VoteStat=~VoteStat where lrn=1

Comment: `UPDATE Voters SET [VoteStat] = 1 WHERE [LRN] = @LRN`

Comment: it doesn't work @AndrewMorton.. I been working on it since 3 hours ago... the value remains false.

Comment: `Dim rows = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows were affected

Comment: @TeacherAi Then it is likely that AddWithValue is messing up the parameter `@LRN`. What is the type of the `[LRN]` column in the database? What is the type of the LRN variable in your program?

Comment: LRN in Database is bigint...LRN in program is Int64

Comment: I tested this code, UPDATE Voters SET [VoteStat] = 1  WHERE [LRN] = 1" and it works..thank you @AndrewMorton.. I think its the LRN ..my problem now is what should I declare with LRN?

Comment: @TeacherAi You treat `LRN` in your code like it is a string-value. Edited my answer.

Comment: @MatSnow, I ommitted some because in ask for more details than code. but those are just  for connection and messageboxes.

Comment: Your title says you are attempting to update a boolean, but a comment says the field is a bigint . . is this part of the problem?

Comment: @peterG The value to be set is a "boolean" but the column in the predicate is a bigint.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```vb
'*** This part is presumably not needed
'*** if the "prevote"-variable is needed after the UPDATE,
'*** then use this part
'Dim prevote As Integer
'
'Using president As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRESIDENT WHERE name=@name", con)
'    president.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
'    prevote = CInt(president.ExecuteScalar) + 1
'End Using
'
'Using president As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE President SET [VoteCount]=@prevote where [Name]=@name", con)
'   president.Parameters.Add("@prevote", SqlDbType.Int).Value = prevote
'   president.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Name
'   president.ExecuteNonQuery()
'End Using
'******************************************

'*** Replaces upper part
'*** If VoteCount just should be incremented by 1 everytime,
'*** then use this part
'*** assumes that only one row exists per "name" in table "PRESIDENT"!
Using president As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE President SET [VoteCount]=(CASE WHEN [VoteCount] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE [VoteCount]+1 END) WHERE [Name]=@name", con)
    president.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name
    president.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
'****************************

Dim LRN As Int64
LRN = CLng(TextBox3.Text)

Using Stud_Vote_Stat As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE Voters SET [VoteStat]=1 WHERE [LRN]=@LRN", con)
    Stud_Vote_Stat.Parameters.Add("@LRN", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = LRN
    Stud_Vote_Stat.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: You get any exception?

Comment: sir, it still doesn't work. I should probably change the LRN to the Voters Name.. I'll try if it will work.

Comment: Should not be necessary. I'm asking again, do you get any exception? `it doesn't work`  is not helping much

Comment: The program does not throw any error. When I click the button where this code is being placed, it has no error. But if I enter the LRN again for the second time, the name of the student still shows instead of a message box telling the student that he or she already voted.

Comment: I suspect the problem is somewhere else in your code. Please update your question with all the relevant code of your `Button_Click`-method

Comment: I tried to replace the LRN int64 with the votersname which is text in db. It now throws something, Additional information: The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator. or Additional information: The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: It is now worki... I change the LRN to voters name and I change the data type of VOtersname in the db to varchar(50).. Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: I think you're also good with the LRN. Maybe the problem was the missing conversion to long. Also wanted to suggest to change data-type of votersname to varchar. ;-)

Comment: `Dim president As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRESIDENT WHERE [name]=@name", con)` would get that part working with just an ExecuteScalar. As it is, the code is setting `prevote` to the *last* returned value of `[VoteCount]` + 1. I suspect that is not intended.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes and probably no. The `SELECT` returns probably only one row everytime. So it worked, but the code still was kind of ugly. If `[VoteCount]` just needs to be incremented by 1 on every run then only one `UPDATE` is necessary. I've edited my answer and added comments.